# .split() on elements of a sentence string, advanced separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, separator

I want to be able to split a sentence string into an array of individual word strings.

```
sentenceArr = 'I take the dog to the park'
sentenceArr.split(' ');
```

Desired result: `['I', 'take', 'the', 'dog', 'to', 'the', 'park']`

This is easy if they are just split by spaces as above, but if there are commas or double spaces, or RegExes in the string it can come unstuck.

```
sentenceArr = 'I take,the  dog to\nthe park'
sentenceArr.split(' ');
```

How can I modify the split() separator argument to account for these irregularities?

Ideally, I want to be able to split anywhere there isn't a letter.

Comment: `sentenceArr.split(/\W+/);` use regex

Comment: Read the documentation for `split` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: What do you mean by *Regexes in the string*?

Comment: Ha, you're right - that isn't regex is it. I was assuming any *slash, letter* expression was also referred to as regex. That's just *new line*. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` also takes a regex as argument :

```js
sentenceArr = 'I take,the  dog to\nthe park'
var r= sentenceArr.split(/\W+/);

console.log(r)
```